# Create Simultaneous Hover Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have done extensive research on how to accomplish this task, but I just can't seem to figure out the appropriate way.

At the moment, I currently have a table cell and I wanted to create two simultaneous hover effects when you scroll over the table cell. First, it will fill the entire table cell with a red background, and at the same time, it will also up the corresponding image opacity to 100%. The opacity sits at 25% when the image isn't be hovered.

For the most part, I have it all working, except for one minor issue. The image is just a small portion of the table cell, and I have to scroll over the image itself to enable to opacity change. If not, it will just fill the table cell background (an example is in the image below). I was wondering if it was possible to link the two hover effects together, so the background-color and image opacity change take place once the table cell is hovered over.

[Example of the current hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9cP4.png)

Here is my HTML code, as well as the CSS that goes along with it.

```
<td class="logo_area" align="center" style="background-color:#eeeeee;border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;">
    <a href="?mode=team&amp;team_id=' . $team_key . '"><img src="/images/logos/50/nhl/' . $team_key . '.png" alt="" border="0" style="opacity:0.25;filter:alpha(opacity=25); margin-top:7px;" /></a>
</td>
```

---

```
.logo_area  {
    height: 65px;
}

.logo_area a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo_area a:hover {
    background-color: #c70000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo_area a img:hover {
    opacity:1.0 !important;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
```

This has been bugging me for several days, so I finally decided to reach out for some assistance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why don't you use ".logo_area:hover a img" and ".logo_area:hover  a". This way, you can reach to ".logo_area" inside elements by hovering on ".logo_area" itself

Answer (score 1):

How about with jQuery?

```
$( ".logo_area" ).hover(function() {
$( this ).css(
"opacity":"1.0",
"background-color:, "#c70000");    
});
```

Comment: This also worked out perfect! I appreciate the help, this will definitely make it easier to add any hover effects as well.

Comment: Yes...you can also get events from that hover as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of your selector

```
.logo_area a:hover img {
  opacity:1.0 !important;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, exactly what I was looking for! Appreciate it!